# systemjs - mapping to different URL

Tags: node.js, angular, systemjs

I am new to angular 2 and systemjs, and I have a sample node.js project where I'm trying to map an angular 2 app in the subfolder './client/dashboard' to a sub URL 'localhost:3000/dashboard' using the express.static middleware:

```
app.use('/dashboard', express.static(__dirname + '/client/dashboard', { maxAge: 86400000 }));
```

[angular 2 app folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbBRB.png)

my index.html has the following code:

```
<base href="/dashboard">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dashboard/styles.css">
<script src="dashboard/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="dashboard/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="dashboard/node_modules/rxjs/rx.js"></script>
<script src="dashboard/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="dashboard/node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="dashboard/node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
<script>
System.config({
    baseURL: '/dashboard',
    // paths: {
    //     '*': 'dashboard/*'
    // },
    map: {
        app: '/dashboard/app',
        rxjs: '/dashboard/node_modules/rxjs',
        angular2: '/dashboard/node_modules/angular2'
    },
    packages: {
        app: { format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        rxjs: { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        angular2: { defaultExtension: 'js' }
    }
});
System.import('app/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

The only errors I'm getting are a 'require is not defined' on rx.ts and a 404 on a css file (see attached pic [chrome errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0rsZ.png))

If I simply map the angular 2 app directory to '/', I still get the arbitrary 'require is not defined' error on rx.ts, but the page loads properly, so I'm pretty sure that isn't the issue. The only other error I'm seeing is the css error. Any ideas what the issue could be? tia

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's because you included twice rxjs and angular2: one using script elements and one within the SystemJS configuration.

Why do you need to define them in the SystemJS configuration?

**Edit**

This should be enough:

```
<base href="/dashboard">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dashboard/styles.css">
<script src="dashboard/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="dashboard/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="dashboard/node_modules/rxjs/rx.js"></script>
<script src="dashboard/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="dashboard/node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="dashboard/node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
<script>
  System.config({
    baseURL: '/dashboard',
    map: {
      app: '/dashboard/app'
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('app/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Comment: I defined them specifically to map the paths from /node_modules/* to /dashboard/node_modules/*. If I don't have the mapping in place, I get 404s trying to load rxjs and angular2 dependencies

Comment: In fact you should only need to map your `app` folder... I updated my answer ;-)

Comment: I tried that configuration, and I'm getting 404's on GET http://localhost:3000/dashboard/angular2/platform/browser 404 (Not Found) and the core and router dependencies